# How to establish glBindBufferRange() offset with Shader Storage Buffer and std430?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to switch between ssbo data to draw things with different setup. To make it happen I need to use `glBindBufferRange()` with its suitable offset.
I've read that the offset needs to be a multiple of `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT` for ubo, but things may be changed with ssbo since using std430 instead of std140.

I tried to do this the easiest way

```cpp
struct Color
{
    float r, g, b, a;
};
struct V2
{
   float x, y;
};
struct Uniform
{
    Color c1;
    Color c2;
    V2 v2;
    float r;
    float f;
    int t;
};

GLuint ssbo = 0;
std::vector<Uniform> uniform;

int main()
{
    //create window, context etc.

    glCreateBuffers(1, &ssbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);

    Uniform u;
    u.c1 = {255, 0, 255, 255 };
    u.c2 = {255, 0, 255, 255 };
    u.v2 = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
    u.r = 0.0f;
    u.f = 100.0f;
    u.t = 0;
    uniform.push_back(u);

    u.c1 = {255, 255, 0, 255 };
    u.c2 = {255, 255, 0, 255 };
    u.v2 = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
    u.r = 100.0f;
    u.f = 100.0f;
    u.t = 1;
    uniform.push_back(u);

    u.c1 = {255, 0, 0, 255 };
    u.c2 = {255, 0, 0, 255 };
    u.v2 = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
    u.r = 100.0f;
    u.f = 0.0f;
    u.t = 0;
    uniform.push_back(u);

    glNamedBufferData(ssbo, sizeof(Uniform) * uniform.size(), uniform.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    for(int i = 0; i < uniform.size(); ++i) {
        glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, ssbo, sizeof(Uniform) * i, sizeof(Uniform));

        glDrawArrays(...);
    }

    //swap buffer etc.

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 f_color;

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer Unif
{
    vec4 c1; 
    vec4 c2; 
    vec2 v2;   
    float r;  
    float f; 
    int t;      
};

void main()
{       
    f_color = vec4(t, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

There is of course vao, vbo, vertex struct and so on, but they are not affect ssbo.

I got `GL_INVALID_VALUE` `glBindBufferRange()` error, though. And that must come from offset, because my next attempt transfers data, but with wrong order.

My next attept was to use `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT`
and a formula I found on the Internet

```cpp
    int align = 4;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT, &align);
    int ssboSize = sizeof(Uniform) + align - sizeof(Uniform) % align;
```

so just changing `glNamedBufferData` and `glBindBufferRange` it looks like this

```cpp
 glNamedBufferData(ssbo, ssboSize * uniform.size(), uniform.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

```cpp
glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, ssbo, ssboSize * i, sizeof(Uniform));
```

and that way, it almost worked. As you can see, `t`s are

```
0;
1;
0;
```

so opengl should draw 3 shapes with colors -

```cpp
vec4(0, 0, 0, 1); 
vec4(1, 0, 0, 1); 
vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

it draws them wrong order

```cpp
vec4(1, 0, 0, 1); 
vec4(0, 0, 0, 1); 
vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

How can I make it transfer data proper way?

Comment: Your code is very confused. You bind the SSBO to binding index 1, but your shader says that it should come from index 3. You say you're rendering something, but your shader never actually writes `gl_Position`, so it can't possibly be drawing anything (it can be doing transform feedback, but rasterization is not possible). Basically, there's a lot wrong with this code, and you need to get it to an [mcve] level before we can talk about the SSBO problem.

Comment: Yes, index was just a copypaste mistake. Already fixed it. Shader never writes `gl_Position` because it is a fragment shader and it writes `f_color`. Adding more code like vertex shader, vao, vbo and more stuff would make me not be able to post it, because of more code than descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

The [OpenGL spec (Version 4.6)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) states the following in section "6.1.1 Binding Buffer Objects to Indexed Target Points" regararding the error conditions for `glBindBufferRange`:

> - An `INVALID_VALUE` error is generated by `BindBufferRange` if `buffer` is
>     non-zero **and `offset` or `size` do not respectively satisfy the constraints described for those parameters for the specified target, as described in section 6.7.1.**

Section 6.7.1 "Indexed Buffer Object Limits and Binding Queries" states for SSBOs:

> - starting offset: `SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_START`
> - **offset restriction: multiple of value of `SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT`**
> - binding size `SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_SIZE`

According to Table 23.64 "Implementation Dependent Aggregate Shader Limits":

> 256 [with the following footnote]: The value of `SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT` is the maximum allowed, not the minimum.

So if your offset is not a multiple of 256 (which it isn't), this code is simply not guaranteed to work at all. You can query for the actual restriction by the implementation you are running on and ajust your buffer contents accordingly, but you **must be** prepared that it is as high as 256 bytes.

Comment: `glGetIntegerv(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT, &align);` returns 32 for me. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes. you ignored the "**multiple of value of** `SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT`" part. 52 is not a multiple of 32.

Comment: So, if I fill the struct to be 64, it will work fine?

Comment: In case of your particular implementation: yes. On another implementation: not guaranteed to work.

Comment: How can I be implementation independent?

Comment: Well. Under the assumption that the alignments will always be powers of two, you can just work with a 256byt alignment for all implementations. Another option would be to re-think your strategy. I.e. don't rebind a buffer range for each draw, instead put an array of `Uniform` structs into the SSBO (as you actually already on client side), and just forward the index to the shaders for each draw call.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `struct alignas(128) Uniform`. I guess my next goal is to not use hardcoded align.